# Android - TextView assignment is not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I have a `button` in my `activity`. When I press it, following method "`ProcessNumbers()`" is called. I need the functionality that **"Processing..."** text should be displayed in the `textview` first, then the `loop` should get processed, and when the `loop` finishes after 2-3 seconds, the `textview` should show **"Processed"** text. But this is not happening. When I click the `button`, `loop` runs first and after 2-3 seconds, the `textview` contains "Processed". Why the first step is missing where `textview` should contain **"Processing..."**?

```
private void ProcessNumbers()
{
        TextView textViewProcessNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProcessNumbers);
        textViewProcessNumbers.setText("Processing...");

        int k = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i <= 1000000000; i++)
        {
                k = 1;
        }

        textViewProcessNumbers.setText("Processed...");
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Instead of for loop use TimerTask.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ProcessNumbers()
{
    TextView textViewProcessNumbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProcessNumbers);
    textViewProcessNumbers.setText("Processing...");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do something after 30000ms
            textViewProcessNumbers.setText("Processed...");
        }
    }, 30000);
}
```

Use handler for delay. Hope it helps

Comment: you can easily change the time from 30000 with whatever you want. this 30000 is in millisecond

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is working. FOR LOOP I am running in the above code sample is just an illustration that some business logic is running. When that business logic is finished, the textview should get updated with the text "Processed". So, I think postDelayed will not work for me. I think the background thread suggested by "PIOTR ZAWADZKI" will be the best fit for me.

Comment: yes you can use AsycTask but you dont mention that in your question. So i just posted delay code

Comment: It's okay, my fault.

Comment: Happy to help you @NareshKumarPrajapati :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move that process to a background thread e.g. using an AsyncTask since textview won't get updated until you leave the main thread.
Executing long running operations on the UI thread is also not recommended and it might cause an Application Not Responding dialog to appear.

So 
1. Set the label to Processing...
2. Start the AsyncTask with your process
2. When AsyncTask finishes update the label in onPostExecute

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can you please give me an example of AsyncTask background thread? That would really be very helpful.

Comment: Sure, you could check out the usage sample here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountDownTimer`, after find text view add this code.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         textViewProcessNumbers.setText("Processing...");
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         textViewProcessNumbers.setText("Processed...");
     }
  }.start();
```

**CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)**